# Reactflow: Custom Background Image

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-flow

I need to create a button, that will let user select an image from computer and then that image will be adding to background pane with zooming along with the nodes.

I already created a custom node that hold image with resiable however with a custom node sometimes depending on order of nodes selected, this custom background node will be displaying in front of other nodes or edges.

I already try to set z-index in custom node but does not work.

If someone know how to help I would be thankfull.